# How to create a bullet animation? (Shooter Game)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to make a shooter game, but I have got some troubles with bullet animation. Each time I click, a new bullet object created and animation starts, but after each click the created bullet disappears and same bullet starts over again which is faster than previous bullet. So I am trying to create new bullet after each click. A basic shooter game logic. Here is my code:

```
    function newBullet(x,y,angle,speed,id,type) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.angle = angle;
    this.radians = this.angle * Math.PI / 180;
    this.id = id;
    this.type = type;
    this.drawBullet = drawBullet;
    this.moveBullet = moveBullet;
    }

    function moveBullet() {
    this.x = this.x + Math.cos(this.radians) * this.speed ;
    this.y = this.y + Math.sin(this.radians) * this.speed;
    ctx.drawImage( bulletImg, this.x, this.y);
    }

    function drawBullet() {
        bullet = new newBullet(playerX,playerY,getAngle(),2,1,1);
        bullets[bullets.length] = bullet;
        setInterval("bullets[bullets.length - 1].moveBullet()", 25);
    }

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",drawBullet,false);
```

Comment: Any chance you accept one of the answers here?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `var` here:

```
    var bullet = new newBullet(playerX,playerY,getAngle(),2,1,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a bullet to an array you should use `push`. This will update `bullets.length`:

```
function drawBullet() {
        var bullet = new newBullet(playerX,playerY,getAngle(),2,1,1);
        bullets.push(bullet);
        setInterval(bullets[bullets.length - 1].moveBullet, 25);
}
```

The reason your created bullet disappeared: you replaced `bullets[0]` each time. And the new bullet was faster then the old one because `bullets[0].moveBullet` was called n-times in each 25ms interval, where n is the number of bullets you "created".